# Stop musicplayer in background,calls,any activity take place - Android

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an audio player app.I want to stop the music when pressed home button , in background, calls , any other activity pops up.

MainActivity.java

```
       public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
          Button dholak01;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    dholak01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1);
    final MediaPlayer dk1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.dholak01);

    //ONCLICK BUTTONS//

    dholak01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (dk1.isPlaying()) {
                dk1.pause();
                dholak01.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dholak);



            } else {
                dk1.start();
                dholak01.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dholakplay);
                dk1.setLooping(true);

            }
        }

    });
```

The music is running when the app runs on background in calls,etc.Simply I want to pause the music while any disturbance occur.(OnPause method).Pls tell where I have to place the code also!